# Jetpack compose navigation - pass parameter to the start destination view model with SavedStateHandle

Tags: android, navigation, android-jetpack-compose

I have a multiple activities application, each has its own navigation graph. I'm able to start an activity with a parameter but I don't know how to correctly get this parameter into the start destination view model.

I use the following architecture to pass parameters between destinations within a single graph. This is working well but I cannot figure out how to pass an argument to the start destination without significantly changing the architecture:

ViewModel:

```
@HiltViewModel
class FooViewModel @Inject constructor(
    savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle
): ViewModel {
    init {
        val param: String = savedStateHandle["foo-param"]
    }
}
```

Activity:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class FooActivity : FragmentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        ...

        val param = intent?.getStringExtra("foo-param") // how do I get this into FooViewModel via the SavedStateHandle

        setContent {
            AppTheme {
                NavHost(
                    navController = navController,
                    startDestination = "foo-route/{foo-param}",
                ) {
                    composable(
                        route = "foo-route/{foo-param}",
                        arguments = listOf(
                            navArgument("foo-param") { type = NavType.StringType },
                        ),
                    ) {
                        FooScreen(viewModel = hiltViewModel())
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need init method in ```ViewModel``` directly access the variable with ```SavedStateHandle```

Comment: Add `defaultValue = intent?.getStringExtra("foo-param")` to your `navArgument("foo-param")`.

Comment: `defaultValue` does the trick. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

**The `startDestination` cannot take parameters. It will always give you the `default` value if set otherwise `null`.**

> how to correctly get this parameter into the start destination view model.

For this the best way to do this is the following as mentioned in comments:

**1.** You can set the parameter using the **default** value in the navigation graph like:

```
composable(
    route = "foo-route/{foo-param}",
    arguments = listOf(
        navArgument("foo-param") {
            type = NavType.StringType
            defaultValue = param // Your parameter goes here
        },
    ),
) {
    FooScreen(viewModel = hiltViewModel())
}
```

You can try some other hacks but these are not appropriate and not recommended.

**2.** You can use another route for the first time something like loading screen and then you can route to your desired screen  with the parameters.

**3.** You can use a `mutableState` and observe the change in the screen and change that value with the parameter to show the required data.

**4.** You can also use `viewModel` to take care about the parameter and screens navigation after getting the required data from database and till then you can show loader and after successfully getting the required data navigate to other screen with parameter.

Comment: None of these are the correct approach. The correct way to do this is to set the `defaultValue` to what you want it to be (in this case, to the extra from the Intent).